# How would I test from one subdirectory to another in vscode using unittest?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I have a project that is put together in the format of the python packaging tutorial in the documentation.

```
Project_Directory/
├── src/
│   └── PROJECT_NAME/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── exampleModule.py
└── tests/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── Test_exampleModule.py
```

I've been using `unittest` to run tests so far (with a workaround), but I'm moving to vscode and was hoping to use the built-in testing features.

Before now, I was able to cd into src/ and run `python3 -m unittest discover .. -p "Test_*.py"` to get my tests to run with just `from PROJECT_NAME import exampleModule`.

Coming to VSCode, the internal testing system can't seem to find my tests while also being able to import the modules.  I changed the python testing arguments for unittest, and nothing seemed to be able to replicate the functionality I had before.  I don't want to have to change all my testing to be `from src.PROJECT_NAME` or something like that.

Comment: @blhsing I mean, projects like [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests), [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/), and [urllib](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3) all do it the way I saw.  It seems like there should be _some_ way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out after looking through multiple other questions, github issues, and poking around in the actual file itself.  For some reason, the value passed into `python.testing.cwd` is... I'm not actually sure, but `unittest` didn't like what setting `"python.testing.cwd": "src"` ended up doing.

To fix the problem and re-create what I had before, my settings.json file needed `"python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"`.  Now my tests run in vscode just like they do in my cli.

Comment: `/src` is an absolute path to a subdir of the root folder, not part of your workspace

Comment: @rioV8 I tried all variants of characters around src. `src`, `./src`, `./src/`, and more. This is finally what ended up working for me.

Comment: those are relative paths but relative to what

Comment: @rioV8 Exactly!  It needed the ${workspaceFolder} to point it to the directory I thought it would be relative to.  This wasn't very evident to me, and I have no idea where it was relative to beforehand, which is why I made it as an answer.

Comment: they are relative to whatever is the `cwd` of the terminal, always use absolute paths